# Use Python xlsx writer conditional formatting to highlight token list in cells

Tags: python, excel, text, highlight, xlsxwriter

Hi I'm working in python to try to highlight conditional format function in the xlsxWriter function with this code:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bold': 10, 'italic': 10, 'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})
    uppercases_worksheet.conditional_format('D1:D100', {'type':     'text',
                                        'criteria': 'containing',
                                        'value':   'girl',
                                        'format':   format1})
```

The problem is this highlights the whole cell containing "girl" in excel rather than just the desired word, in this case "girl." Thank you,

Comment: That is how conditional formatting works in Excel. It isn’t possible to conditionally format just of a string.

Comment: You need to use the write_rich_string method of the worksheet class in order to achieve this. Have a look at the documentation here https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-rich-string and https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html